# I want to restore my project in my yesterday file in Xcode, how can i do that?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner in the iOS development, Now i am trying to debug my code

As we know, Xcode is autosaving. I am debugging a chunk of code right now, But i am messed up, somehow it didn't work properly, I have tried using control + Z to get back, but it still didn't work.

I want to back to my yesterday Xcode project file, but the problem is, i have not made any backup, and i have not made local repository. Can get my previous version file back?

does it work if i use git reset ?

```
git reset
```

Comment: Learn how to use `git` inside of Xcode. Right now, you *can't* do anything. But had you (1) set up a local git repository, (2) committed at the right point yesterday you could easily discard any new changes Xcode "autosaved".

Answer (score 3):

*You should use [Github](https://github.com/) for saving your project by committing daily updates*

**OR**
You can recover some of files using **TextEdit**

By using **TextEdit** App you can view and restore past versions of documents.

**Step 1:**
**Open your document file using TextEdit.**

[image] 
**Step 2:**

**TextEdit ->File->Revert To->Browse All Version**
[image]

**Stpe: 3:**

**Select files from old dates whichever you want & click restore.**
[image]

[Apple Guide](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25757?locale=en_GB)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there no way to go back. No repo, no CRT+Zm no copies? I dont see any option.

PD: Create a local repot

Answer (score 0):

'git reset' will not work for you. You should have setup a Git repository with timely commits. Create a git repo now so that you will not face the same situation later.